# (url-retrieve) Symbol's value as variable is void

Tags: variables, elisp

I have a function to retrieve an IP from a github repo. I get the error "Symbol's value as variable is void: response" the first time I call the function, but any subsequent calls after the first are successful. I tried adding (require 'url) but to no avail.

```
(defun get-ip ()
  (let ((url-request-method "GET")
        (url-request-extra-headers 
         '(("Authorization" . "token xxxxxxxxx")
       ("Accept" . "application/vnd.github.v3.raw"))))
    (progn (url-retrieve "https://api.github.com/repos/xxxxxxx" 
             (lambda (status)
               (progn (setq response (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max)))
                  (kill-buffer (current-buffer))))
             nil
             'silent)
       (string-match "\\([0-9]*\\.[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*\\)" response)
       (match-string 0 response))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not create a global `response` variable. Add it to your `let` form instead, so that it is local to the `defun`.  See also https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html

More fundamentally, `url-retrieve` is an asynchronous function: the code which attempts to set `response` will not yet have a buffer to operate on when `url-retrieve` has finished evaluating (it will continue in the background, and eventually call its callback in the `lambda`, but there is no guarantee that this happens during the execution of your form).  The simple but slightly clunky solution is to switch to `url-retrieve-synchronously` and live with the fact that it could take a while.

You also need to take care to avoid clobbering the user's buffer, their position within that buffer, or the regex match history.

With these fixes, it is also natural to factor out `response` entirely.

```
(defun get-ip ()
  (let ((url-request-method "GET")
        (url-request-extra-headers 
         '(("Authorization" . "token xxxxxxxxx")
       ("Accept" . "application/vnd.github.v3.raw"))))
    (save-match-data
      (save-current-buffer
        (set-buffer
         (url-retrieve-synchronously "http://www.google.com/" 'silent))
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (if (search-forward-regexp "\\([0-9]*\\.[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*\\)" nil t)
            (match-string 0) "")))))
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I had also tried creating the variable inside the `let` block. In this case I get a different error, "Wrong type argument: stringp, nil"

Comment: I refactored this answer substantially. I still don't have a way to repro your precise code without the proper URL you want to use, so this might still fail.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've been trying to get this working for the past few days, but without success. For whatever reason `url-retrieve` works with my authentification info, but `url-retrieve-synchronously` doesn't. I'm not sure what do to at this point.

Comment: What is this code supposed to accomplish? Would it be acceptable if it updated a variable in the background and then displayed the result in the minibuffer whenever it's ready, for example? You can't then have other code fetch the IP address, other than by extending the callback chain.

Comment: I have a server at home with a dynamic IP. The server regularly checks its IP, and updates a github repo with the new IP when it changes. The idea is for me to remotely know the server IP by checking the repo. Hence I want a function which returns the IP of my server, and then passes this IP to other functions. I found a workaround by using `make-term`, passing a curl command which returns the IP, and parsing the whole buffer to find the IP. It works but it is not as beautiful/simple as getting the ip with `url-retrieve-synchronously`.